# Is it normal that one git repository can trigger multiple code pipeline?

Tags: git, repository, aws-codepipeline

Is it normal that one git repository can trigger multiple code pipeline?
Or should git repository and codepipeline be 1-1 mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a quiet common scenario that one repo triggers multiple pipelines. Some use cases (non-exhaustive enumeration):

- Different pipelines for master branch und feature branches
- Depending on directory where files are committed different builds may be triggered (eg only build and create and publish a library)
- Special case: empty pipeline. For instance if only in a directory with documentation something was changed.
- Special build for Quality assurance which aso triggers integration tests, includes static code analysis, or whatever you may think of.